# Links on Google result list with unnecessary parameters

Tags: seo, google, htaccess, url-rewriting, canonical-url

I have a website that uses *.htaccess* to turn the parameterized URLs into a folder pattern based URL

For example :

```
www.example.com?lang=de&cat=mycategory
```

becomes

```
www.example.com/de/mycategory
```

Now Google lists this page as

```
www.example.com/de/category?lang=de&cat=mycategory
```

in its result list and I don't know why. I check the website's source code but the link www.example.com/de/category?lang=de&cat=mycategory is not in the source code, so I don't know why Google comes up with this kind of link.

The rewrite rule in my *.htaccess* file looks like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^de/mycategory /index.php?lang=de&cat=mycategory [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 3):

The source of your problem can be in html or in javascript, and you cannot control the links that other people put on the net too.. And because he finds a page when making a request for it, it indexes it. I miss some information to give answer with code (using a CMS? Other rules in .htaccess, etc…), but here are some ways :

1. Write a permanent redirect in .htaccess to remove the query string,
   but then beware of the redirect loop (/de/mycat ->
   /index.php?lang=de&cat=mycat -> index.php)
2. Usually this kind of situation is managed by the CMS: everything
   that is not a static file existing on disk goes to index.php file,
   which will check for the correctness of url and send redirects if
   needed.
3. You should also go to [Google Webmaster Tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/), and have a look where
   they give crawling statistics. There is a page where you can tell
   them what does which parameters in URL.
4. Use a [robots.txt](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062608?hl=en) file to disallow Google/other bots from crawling and indexing some of your files.